# Printing Exception Message in java

Tags: java, exception

Is there a way to print an exception message in Java without the exception?

When I try the following piece of code:

```
try {
    // statements
} catch (javax.script.ScriptException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

The output is:

```
Invalid JavaScript code: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException:
missing } after property list (<Unknown source>) in <Unknown source>; 
at line number 1
```

Is there a way to print the message without the exception information, source and line number information. In other words, the message I would like to print in the output is:

```
missing } after property list
```

Comment: You can parse exception message string to get only those pieces you want

Comment: How about just using println with the message you want to output without the getMessage method?

Comment: You use `getCause()` to get the inner-most exception and `getMessage()` on that, but I wouldn't guarantee that the line number won't be there. It's a rather unusual usecase, can you tell what you want to do? If you just want to output a user-friendly message for a front-end, you're just gonna have to customize it, if it's meant for devs anyway -- the whole thing is much friendlier.

Answer (score 25):

The output looks correct to me:

```
Invalid JavaScript code: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: missing } after property list (<Unknown source>) in <Unknown source>; at line number 1
```

I think `Invalid Javascript code: ..` is the start of the exception message.

Normally the stacktrace isn't returned with the message:

```
try {
    throw new RuntimeException("hu?\ntrace-line1\ntrace-line2");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage()); // prints "hu?"
}
```

So maybe the code you are calling catches an exception and rethrows a `ScriptException`. In this case maybe `e.getCause().getMessage()` can help you.

Answer (score 2):

> In Java, there are three methods to print an exception information.

***1. java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace() method***

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

***2.toString() method :***

```
catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
```

***3. java.lang.Throwable.getMessage() method***

```
catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
              
        }
```

Answer (score -11):

```
try {
} catch (javax.script.ScriptException ex) {
// System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```